# Double in for instead of int

Tags: c++, for-loop

I need to make iterations but the nº of iter necessary is bigger then the bigger int_max (max integer) in C++, can I use the double in for like this?

```cpp
double ntrys = x

for(double i = 0; i < ntrys; i++){


//code here

}
```

I tried like the way above but it seems that it goes to a infinite loop

Comment: [Your code can be a finite loop.](https://ideone.com/ZTv0NG). Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ah, you are dealing with a large number... Then be careful about the presicion of `double`.

Comment: why you dont use "long", instead?

Comment: For what value of `x`? Can you provide a [mcve]? Note that there are langer integers than `int` and that for `double`, `i + 1` will be the same value as `i`, simply because it can't represent such a small change while preserving the most significant digits.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the x value will be  (10^6)*8192

Comment: @gfreitas82 Use `long long` then (or more verbosely, `int64_t`). It can store values up to around 1e18. I started writing an answer how to go beyond that, but that doesn't seem to be needed (or reasonable in any existing computer).

Comment: I suspect that your code feels infinite because it takes a long time to do over eight billion iterations of whatever the loop does. If one iteration takes a microsecond, your loop takes over two hours.

Comment: @molbdnilo the code its very optimized, with 1E5 * 8192 it only took 20 min, the code has being running about 36 hours now, in a 32 threads pc

Comment: @Yksisarvinen and what do you do in the for?   for(long long int i = 0; ...) ?

Comment: Well, yes, `long long` in for both the counter variable and the `ntrys`. Also, note that number of threads don't mean anything unless you write your code for multithreading.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thank you, and yes of course im using multithreading

Comment: You have so many other options that are better than `double` - for example; `long`, `long long`, `unsigned long long` - do you really need more than that?

Answer (score 2):

You can, but a 64-bit integer type is recommended instead. The reason is that `double` decreases precision as the numbers get bigger; when you get to approximately 2 to the power of 53, you will find that `i++` doesn't add 1 any more - it adds 0. And then your loop is infinite.

64-bit integer types are `int64_t` and `uint64_t` from `<stdint.h>`. (You could use `long long` or on some platforms `long`, but why would you?)